# SQL Server Save Changes in Field after Update

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ssms

Good afternoon.

I am stuck in a stored procedure, lets say I have TableA and I want to Update to table A in the Bottom but Writing userwas useris in tableB

[image]

When I update values 1 by 1 I am able to save table B as it looks, but Im stuck when trying the update using where City = 'London'

Update [Table B]

SET UserIs = 'A8'

, UserWas = **( select User from [Table A] where City = 'London' )** **** ERROR

WHERE Id in (SELECT Id From [Table A] where City = 'London' )

( London comes from a Variable)

UPDATE [Table A]

SET USER = 'A8'

WHERE City = 'London'

Comment: Since you're updating both UserWas and UserIs in Table B, what are the values for those two records before the update?

Comment: Or are you logging the change in User (in which case you're inserting into Table B rather than updating)?

Comment: Good morning, im inserting into table B when thr stores procedure is executes.

Comment: I am updating both!

Comment: I'm trying to use OUTPUT in order to complete this step, but Im not sure if its the right path to follow.

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "I am updating both".  Bear in mind that I haven't been working on this as long as you have, so things that are obvious to you aren't obvious to me.  Add your current stored procedure to your question and I'll take a look at it.